# Wicket - Render Errors Not Logged on App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, wicket, wicket-6

I'm new to Wicket but I'm having a hard time finding this answer. When I have a rendering errors, say a component throws a NullPointerException, the rendering crashes but no error is logged to the App Engine logs. It registers a 500 status on the request but the stack trace is missing from the logs. I'm sure I'm missing a simple configuration but I can't seem to figure out what it would be. Any ideas as to how I can properly setup error logging with Wicket on Google App Engine?

Comment: I haven't used Wicket, but how is logging managed by it? Is it using java.util.logging.Logger? If so, with which level is Wicket doing the logging?

Comment: is `getConfigurationType()` in your application set to `RuntimeConfigurationType.DEVELOPMENT`?

Comment: @Mario correct, App Engine Logging is handled by java.util.logging.Logger and I suspect that Wicket probably isn't setup to use that. I need to figure out how to set the logger on the framework.

Comment: @Martin I have RuntimeConfigurationType.DEPLOYMENT set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort of got this working based on [this post](http://blog.xam.de/2010/03/logging-in-google-appengine-for-java.html). The errors render as warnings instead of error or critical but it's better than nothing.

1. Add the following jar files to WEB-INF/lib

   - log4j-1.2.17.jar
   - slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
   - slf4j-simple-1.7.7.jar
2. Create file: src/main/resources/log4j.properties
3. In log4j.properties, enter the following:

   log4j.rootLogger=WARN, console
   log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
   log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
   log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] - %m%n

   log4j.logger.org.apache.wicket=WARN